# Running a Hello World program (basic) in Sencha touch

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have 2 questions, regarding `Sencha touch` and `phone gap` ;

I am reading SenchaTouch CookBook by Ajith kumar. I am following the example programs given in the 1st chapter. So according to that i did the following.

THis is my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Yapps! - Your daily applications!</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="sencha-
                touch/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" type="text/css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="sencha-
                    touch/resources/css/yapps-all.css" type="text/css">
                <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
                    src="phonegap.1.0.0.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="sencha-
                    touch/sencha-touch.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
                    src="ch01/ch01_03.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="sencha-
                    touch/yapps-all.js"></script>



        </head>
        <body></body>
    </html>
```

The `ch01_03.js` file. The told to add these .JS files inside the WWW folder, but i am unable to add any files inside that folder therefore i added it out of the folder.

```
Ext.setup({
          onReady: function() {
          ￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼var supportedFeatures = "Ext.supports.AudioTag : " +
          (Ext.supports.AudioTag ? "On" : "Off");
          supportedFeatures += "\nExt.supports.CSS3BorderRadius : " +
          (Ext.supports.CSS3BorderRadius ? "On" : "Off");
          supportedFeatures += "\nExt.supports.CSS3DTransform : " +
          (Ext.supports.CSS3DTransform ? "On" : "Off");
          supportedFeatures += "\nExt.supports.CSS3LinearGradient : " +
          (Ext.supports.CSS3LinearGradient ? "On" : "Off");
          supportedFeatures += "\nExt.supports.Canvas : " +
          (Ext.supports.Canvas ? "On" : "Off");
          supportedFeatures += "\nExt.supports.DeviceMotion : " +
          (Ext.supports.DeviceMotion ? "On" : "Off");
          supportedFeatures += "\nExt.supports.Float : " +
          (Ext.supports.Float ? "On" : "Off");
          supportedFeatures += "\nExt.supports.GeoLocation : " +
          (Ext.supports.GeoLocation ? "On" : "Off");
          supportedFeatures += "\nExt.supports.History : " +
          (Ext.supports.History ? "On" : "Off");
          supportedFeatures += "\nExt.supports.OrientationChange : " +
          (Ext.supports.OrientationChange ? "On" : "Off");
          supportedFeatures += "\nExt.supports.RightMargin : " +
          (Ext.supports.RightMargin ? "On" : "Off");
          supportedFeatures += "\nExt.supports.SVG : " +
          (Ext.supports.SVG ? "On" : "Off");
          supportedFeatures += "\nExt.supports.Touch : " +
          (Ext.supports.Touch ? "On" : "Off");
          supportedFeatures += "\nExt.supports.Transitions : " +
          (Ext.supports.Transitions ? "On" : "Off");
          supportedFeatures += "\nExt.supports.TransparentColor : " +
          (Ext.supports.TransparentColor ? "On" : "Off");
          supportedFeatures += "\nExt.supports.VML : " +
          (Ext.supports.VML ? "On" : "Off");
          Ext.Msg.alert("INFO", supportedFeatures);
          }
          });
```

1.) The problem is that i am only seeing a blank screen when i run it on my iPhone and Stimulator. What is this happening, and what should i do to get the Alert displayed on the view ?

2.) I need to detect if the device i am running the application. In the book it shows how to detect an iPad, Android application and Blackberry. But not an iPhone. How can i detect an iPhone ?

```
Ext.setup({
          onReady: function() {

          if (Ext.is.Android)
          Ext.Msg.alert("INFO", "Welcome Android user!");
          if (Ext.is.Blackberry)
          Ext.Msg.alert("INFO", "Welcome Blackberry user!");
          if (Ext.is.iPad)
          Ext.Msg.alert("INFO", "Welcome iPad user!");

          } });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question is tagged under `sencha-touch-2`, I assume that you are using Sencha Touch 2.

[`Ext.is`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.is) is deprecated for Sencha Touch version 2.0

Instead, you can use `Ext.env.OS` package to detect the operating system, that is being running on the device.

Also, you can use the is property to detect a p'cular device like iPad, iPhone, Android etc ..

- `Ext.os.is.Android` : Android platform
- `Ext.os.is.iPhone` : iPhone
- `Ext.os.is.iPad` : iPad etc ..

**EDIT :**

Yes, you can detect the p'cular device. Check the below code ...

```
var navigation = Ext.global.navigator,
    userAgent = navigation.userAgent,
    osEnv, osName, deviceType;

Ext.os = osEnv = new this(userAgent, navigation.platform);

osName = osEnv.name;

var search = window.location.search.match(/deviceType=(Tablet|Phone)/),
nativeDeviceType = window.deviceType;

if (search && search[1]) {
    deviceType = search[1];
}
else if (nativeDeviceType === 'iPhone') {
    deviceType = 'Phone';
}
else if (nativeDeviceType === 'iPad') {
    deviceType = 'Tablet';
}
```

Good example on [**Sencha Touch MVC with PhoneGap**](http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/)

Comment: 1.) Thank you for your reply.But still in xCode it doesn't suggest `iPhone` (it suggest android, iPad and blackberry but no iPhone). 2.) I think in index.html i am referring to a file which is not in the correct file path. I have not added `ch01/ch01_03.js` inside the `WWW` folder, i have added it outside the `WWW` folder since i was not allowed to add files in the `WWW` folder. So how could i access the `cho1_03.js` file ?

Comment: You need to include that file inside the `www` folder, otherwise it won't be accessible. Why you are not able to add it inside `www` folder?

Comment: Even after i add the files to the WWW folder it still displays a White screen, I think there might be something wrong in my index.html file. I have no clue

Comment: You try to run it in browser first. Check if it's running and check the chrome console log .. Then go for running on device.

Comment: I think i will have to scrap this project and start all over again. Is there a good step by step tutorial that shows to run a Hello world program using xCode, phone gap and sencha touch on the browser and device.. :(

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have downloaded PhoneGap, and when i try to create the xCODE project i created it as a `Coedova-Based-Application`. But your tutorial says to create a `Phone gap based application`. Are these 2 the same ?